# Dynamic next and previous elements in swiper.js slider

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I made the following slider with swiper js

```
<Swiper
    loop={true}
    slidesPerView={1.25}
    freeMode={true}
    centeredSlides={true}
    spaceBetween={30}
    keyboard={true}
    modules={[
      Keyboard,
      Navigation,
    ]}
    navigation={{
      nextEl: '.swiper-slide-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-slide-prev',
    }}
    breakpoints={{
      1024: {
        slidesPerView: 2.125,
      },
      768: {
        slidesPerView: 1.5,
      },
    }}
    onSlideChange={(swiper) => {
      /******************************** 
        THIS DOESN'T WORKS 
      ********************************/
      swiper.navigation.nextEl = document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-next') as HTMLElement
      swiper.navigation.prevEl = document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-prev') as HTMLElement
    }}
  >
    {slides.map(slide => (
      <SwiperSlide key={slide.id}>
        ...
      </SwiperSlide>
    ))}
  </Swiper>
```

Now swiper automatically assigns and updates the `.swiper-slide-next` (red) and `.swiper-slide-prev` (green) *classes* to expected elements right away but `swiper.navigation.nextEl` and `swiper.navigation.prevEl` *HTMLElements* doesn't updates. I tried updating them by listening to the `onSlideChange` listener but that didn't work either.

What should I do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image: Swiper next and previous element]

Comment: Are you trying to display your custom next and previous element? Or just a default style.

Comment: @PeterK I am not looking for styling those elements, rather I want those elements to be pointing to the dynamic next and previous slides instead of the bydefault static right and left arrows respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From swiper js documentation: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-slideToClickedSlide :

We have a `slideToClickedSlide` property, exactly for the purpose this question is looking for.